# var/www/ permissions

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have purchases a server today and I am almost through configuring it, I have managed to install mysql and have enabled a firewall which allows access to ports 80, 22 and 443

I am trying to test out a simple php file to see whether all is well but I get a `404 Not found error`, I am certain that this file exists which was created using vi as I have confirmed it using Filezilla.

What am I missing? is there another step that I must take to allow a simple php file to work.

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/69685/what-user-should-own-var-www-on-ubuntu-9-04-server http://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did you configure it as a LAMP server during the installation, or did you install apache yourself?

If apache is not already installed you can install it using the command:

```
sudo aptitude install apache2
```

Also make sure that the correct permissions are setup for apache to access the directory that contains your php file:

```
sudo chmod -R 744 /myphpdir
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /myphpdir
```

Comment: chmod 777 is a horrible idea from a security perspective. This would let anyone on the system (or any compromised account) read/edit/run the php scripts you've written. Any scripts that you write with stored MySQL credentials or other sensitive information are open to the world.

Comment: I know. That was just to let him get it working. Please change it to something more secure -  I suggest 744. I have edited my answer now :)

Comment: @mk_89: if you've made it to the end of this lengthy internet debate, there's some great advice on securing an Apache install over at [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77/apache-server-hardening).

Answer (score 1):

The file has to be readable by the webserver which usually means by the user www-data. Are you sure your document root is /var/www? Is mod_php enabled?

```
# sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
# sudo a2enmod php5
```

This way apache php support should be enabled. If it says "Module php5 already enabled" everything is fine.

What permissions does /var/www have?
And more important, what is the value for DocumentRoot in your apache configuration? (somewhere /etc/apache2/ where your vhosts are defined)

Comment: I don't know how to check if it is installed, im searching on google.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? The steps to enable PHP and configure apache differ slightly depending on your distribution.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, I typed in php -v and it returned something, if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need apache or lighttpd

If you didn't pre-configure as a LAMP on install you can follow this [ApacheMySQLPHP Ubuntu tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)